# Template Based Class Variable

Tags: c++, oop

I'm working on a game and I want to make a base Actor class that holds Stat values that are shared among a variety of Actor types, but I'm having an issue understanding how I can accomplish this without having the base class having a different Stats variable than the actor types...

This is exactly what I have made right now (as shown in the code)... However, I want to somehow make the BaseActor "stats" type become either a PlayerStats or a MonsterStats object when it is created...This way the PlayerActor and MonsterActor no longer need the different "monster_stats" and "player_stats" objects as they inherit the correct type from BaseActor. Is this possible? I'm thinking it can be done through templates, but I'm not too versed in those.

```
class BaseStats {
public:
   int defense;

private:
};

class MonsterStats : public BaseStats {
public:
   int drop_rate;
private:
};

class PlayerStats : public BaseStats {
public:
   int attack_power;
private:
};

class BaseActor {
public:
   BaseStats stats;

private:
};

class MonsterActor : public BaseActor {
public:
   MonsterStats monster_stats;

private:
};

class PlayerActor : public BaseActor {
public:
   PlayerStats player_stats;

private:
};
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with templates and there is a nice OOP answer. I suggest you remove the `template` tag

Comment: I am afraid this question is too broad for StackOverflow. Any answer would have to cover OOP, inheritance, C++ templates, etc.

Comment: @Jeffrey thanks, I added the tag as I assumed this would be possible through templates (as this would be the case in C#).

Answer (score 2):

Have `PlayerStats` and `MonsterStats` derive from `BaseStats`. Have the constructor of each derived `BaseActor` allocate the stats with:

```
MonsterActor::MonsterActor()
{
    m_stats = make_shared<MonsterStats>();
}
```

and have

```
std::shared_ptr<BaseStats> m_stats;
```

in the base class.

Comment: Nice, this looks like it could work! Is it possible to access m_stats still from the Base class? For example if I made defense a private value and made a public GetDefense method in the BaseActor class? (Off the bat it looks like I can't)

Comment: Yes, but only as a base class, and that's where it gets tricky. You need to have a nice abstract API. Like `takeDamage()` or `update()`

Answer (score 0):

Look for Jeffrey's answer for a better way. But since you wanted to do this through templates (which is not recommended): -

```
template <typename T>
class BaseActor {
public:
   T stats;
};

class MonsterActor : public BaseActor<MonsterStatus> {
public:

};

class PlayerActor : public BaseActor<PlayerStatus> {
public:

};
```

Comment: Almost. The problem is that `stats = MonsterStats();` will slice the object. A pointer (ideally shared) is needed.

Comment: @Jeffrey Got it.
Answer has been changed

Comment: Thanks, why is it not recommended to do it this way?

Comment: @Rick Because compiler creates copies of the same class to achieve the functionality.
There would be essentially two BaseActor classes.

Comment: Interesting... but I don't see why this would be a big issue or an issue at all? @EReload

Comment: @Rick Why would you want to add an extra copy your class.
If in future, you would want to add more kind of 'status', this problem can escalate.